# size in Memory of handle object property

Tags: matlab, oop, memory, properties, dynamic-properties

Hi I'm using an object with superclass dynamicprops & matlab.mixin.Copyable

Now I would like to now the size (memorywise) of each of the dynamic properties. I tried stuff like whos and getfield. But it seems like I have a very hard time to find something.

I know that people strugle to get exactly this for handle objects, which this is one of them... But I was wondering if somebody has a solution on that nevertheless.

yours
magu_

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`properties`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/properties.html) function to get a list of properties exposed by an object. The same can be done using [`metaclass`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/metaclass.html). You can then iterate over them and use `x.(p)` syntax to access each by name ([dynamic field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/08/20/advanced-matlab-dynamic-field-names/)). You would determine the size memory-wise the same way you do any other variable (`size`/`class` or `whos`).

Note that you might need to recursively traverse the properties in case they are containers themselves (objects, structs, cell-arrays).

Comment: Thx for the answer but I'm not sure if this really get's all the info. This code: clear all
n = 1e6;
A = cell(1,n);
whos A
B = A;
for i=1:n
    B{i} = 1;
end
whos B
C = zeros(1,n);
whos C
produces A = 4MB; B = 68 MB; C = 8 MB. There must be some overhead somewhere meaning a Cell needs more than merly the structure itself + the data. I think Matlab uses some mxArray informations to store what kind of Datatype it is. Maybe ths accounts for the rest